# Why did the universe have a low entropy at the big bang?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, entropy, big-bang

Sean Carroll, in his book "From Eternity to Here", asks the following question. Why did the universe have a low entropy at the big bang?

in John Cramer version of the Wheeler - Feynman absorber theory, a source that is not matched up with a future absorber emits two waves. An advanced wave into the past and a retarded wave into the future. The advanced wave is supressed by reflection off the big bang. Near this singular creation event the advanced wave arriving from the future is reflected back into the future with 180 degrees phase change. The reflected wave, now a retarded wave traveling into the future, cancels out the source's advanced wave and reinforces the source's retarded wave resulting in no observable advanced waves.

Because of this temporal feedback, in Cramer's big bang as a big mirror assumption the system represented by the universe near the singular creation event continuously emits retarded waves into the future, thus reducing its entropy.

Attempted answer. The universe had a lower entropy at the big bang because of what would happen at and after the big bang, not what had happened. This temporal feedback is the reason for the low entropy of the big bang.

How would a serious physicist qualify an answer like this?

Comment: Hi IMHO any qualification would be along the lines of, "this idea may be true and if we could figure out a way to test it, as say we tested and confirmed the CMB, then that would give it support". Have you read "cycles of time" by penrose?

Comment: More on [low entropy at Big Bang](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+low+entropy+big+bang).